# Are there any issues if importing modules x times from a function?

Tags: python, import, pypdf

I extracted and placed the [PyPDF2 1.26.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2/1.26.0) toolkit into my plugin directory. The hierarchy looks like this:

```
plugin
  |__example.py
  |__report
       |__PyPDF2
            |__(PyPDF2 contents)
```

In the beginning of the `example.py` file, I tried to import the PyPDF2 module using:

```
from report.PyPDF2.PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error:

> ImportError: No module named report.PyPDF2.PyPDF2

But I can import it using `sys`:

```
import os, sys

class plugin:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        ...

    def pdf_merger(self):
        # Import PyPDF2
        sys.path.append(str(self.plugin_dir) + '/report/PyPDF2')        
        from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

        merger = PdfFileMerger()
        return merger

    def func(self):
        merger = self.pdf_merger()
        ...
```

---

The issue is that `func()` will be called multiple times, so each time `from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger` will be run. Would this cause any problems (i.e. memory issues or such) and why could I not import the module using `from report.PyPDF2.PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I extracted and placed the PyPDF2 1.26.0 toolkit into my plugin directory

I don't know what your "plugin directory" is, but that's not the way to install a python package. You want to use something like `pip` instead, preferably with a `virtualenv`.

> ImportError: No module named report.PyPDF2.PyPDF2

I assume the first "PyPDF2" directory is the github root directory (cf https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2). This directory is not a [proper python package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) (it doesn't have an `__init__.py` file) but the project's directory. What you want is to only have the "second-level" PyPDF2 directory (which *is* the actual python package) in "report", and then import from it using `from report.PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger`.

But once again, this is not the right way to install a python package, cf above.

```
def pdf_merger(self):
    # Import PyPDF2
    sys.path.append(str(self.plugin_dir) + '/report/PyPDF2')        
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
```

This will keep on appending to `sys.path` over and over and over again (which might indeed end up causing memory issues by itself if your process runs for a few weeks or months, and depending on how often this function is called). IOW : **don't do that**. Properly install PyPDF2 as a dependancy instead (once again, `pip` and `virtualenv` are your friends) or *at least* only install the "inner" PyPDF2 package as explained above.

Note that the problem here is not with importing the same module over and over again (the very first import will cache the module) but with appending to `sys.path` over and over again. The only issue with a "local" import is a very slight performance hit but you would probably never notice it unless this is a critical function called in a very tight loop).

Also and while we're at it:

```
    sys.path.append(str(self.plugin_dir) + '/report/PyPDF2')
```

1/ there's no need to pass `self.plugin_dir` to `str` (it's alreay one), and 
2/ hardcoding path separators is a very bad idea - you want `os.path.join(self.plugin_dir, 'report', 'PyPDF2')` instead (well in this case you actually want none of this - leave `sys.path` alone and properly install PyPDF2 instead)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used `pip` before but wanted to see if this method would work (which it does to some extent) :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
from report.PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
```

Anyway, imported modules are cached, so don't worry if you import one many times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue still remains.